# Add a subsequent number to the existing number that was already added

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am new to vb.net and I am having trouble in solving this program our teacher asked us to do.

I already spent hours with this program and and I cannot make it done. I have a lot of other assignments to do and pass it before deadline. Thanks in advance if you can help. Here's the problem.

The
Calculate button’s Click event procedure should add the item price to the total of the prices already entered; this amount represents the subtotal owed by the customer. The procedure should display the subtotal on the form. It also should display a 5% sales tax, the shipping charge, and the grand total owed by the customer. The grand total is calculated by adding together the subtotal, the 5% sales tax, and a $6.50 shipping charge. For example, if the user enters 15.75 as the price and then clicks the Calculate button, the button’s Click event procedure should display 15.75 as the subtotal, 0.79 as the sales tax, 6.50 as the shipping charge, and 23.04 as the total due. If the user subsequently enters 10 as the price and then clicks the Calculate button, the button’s Click event procedure should display 25.75 as the subtotal, 1.29 as the sales tax, 6.50 as the shipping charge, and 33.54 as the total due. However, when the subtotal is at least $100, the shipping charge is 0.00. Test the application appropriately.

Here is my code :

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        Const charge_SalesTax As Decimal = 0.05D
        Const charge_Shipping As Decimal = 6.5D


        Dim decItemPrice As Decimal
        Dim decSubtotal As Decimal
        Dim decSalesTax As Decimal
        Dim decShipping As Decimal
        Dim decTotalDue As Decimal

        Dim rndSalesTax As Decimal
        Dim rndShipping As Decimal
        Dim rndTotalDue As Decimal


        Dim intItemPrice As Integer
        Dim intSubTotal As Integer
        Dim intSalesTax As Integer
        Dim intShipping As Integer
        Dim intTotalDue As Integer

        Integer.TryParse(txtItemPrice.Text, intItemPrice)
        Integer.TryParse(lblSubTotal.Text, intSubTotal)
        Integer.TryParse(lblSalesTax.Text, intSalesTax)
        Integer.TryParse(lblShipping.Text, intShipping)
        Integer.TryParse(lblTotalDue.Text, intTotalDue)

        decItemPrice = Val(txtItemPrice.Text)
        lblSubTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(decItemPrice)
        decSalesTax = Val(txtItemPrice.Text) * charge_SalesTax
        rndSalesTax = Math.Round(decSalesTax, 2)
        lblSalesTax.Text = Convert.ToString(rndSalesTax)
        decShipping = charge_Shipping
        lblShipping.Text = Convert.ToString(decShipping)
        decTotalDue = decItemPrice + decSalesTax + decShipping
        rndTotalDue = Math.Round(decTotalDue, 2)
        lblTotalDue.Text = Convert.ToString(rndTotalDue)
```

I was having trouble on how to calculate the Sales Tax if I add additional number on the item price, the additional number that I will enter should add the existing number that I already added on the Item Price and that should calculate the Sales Tax, Shipping and Total Due. I tried to do it by using if else but I don't know where to place it.

Comment: `Integer.TryParse(txtItemPrice.Text, intItemPrice)` then `decItemPrice = Val(txtItemPrice.Text)`. Start from here: does it make sense? -- Decimal has a `TryParse()` method, too. Which is used to validate the input, not to simply avoid exceptions when parsing it. *Test the application appropriately* makes it homework. You skipped the Tour, maybe stop by the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) a moment.

Comment: Even if I did not use a decimal TryParse, this code was already working, what the code is lacking is that I need to input a new number on the existing number that I already input on the item price and that should calculate the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important part of this code is the form level variable `decSubtotal`. This keeps its value between button clicks.

I used the `.ToString` method on the `Decimal` values. I added a parameter to display the proper number of decimals or the currency format. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings where this bit of magic is explained.

```
Private decSubtotal As Decimal

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim decSalesTax As Decimal
    Dim decShipping As Decimal = 0
    Dim decTotalDue As Decimal
    Dim InputPrice As Decimal
    Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, InputPrice)
    decSubtotal += InputPrice
    Label1.Text = decSubtotal.ToString("C")
    decSalesTax = decSubtotal * 0.065D
    Label2.Text = decSalesTax.ToString("N2")
    If decSubtotal < 100 Then
        decShipping = 6.5D
    End If
    Label3.Text = decShipping.ToString("N2")
    decTotalDue = decSubtotal + decSalesTax + decShipping
    Label4.Text = decTotalDue.ToString("C")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the subtotal so that it is carried over from one button click to the next.  The scope of every variable declared inside the `btnCalc_Click` function is local to a single function call.  It is not preserved from one button click to the next.

The subtotal variable needs to live somewhere outside the `btnCalc_Click` function.  The most sensible place would be as a member variable of the `Form1` class.  Your code would look something like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _subtotal As Decimal = 0.0

    Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        ' Insert your code that reads the entered item price

        ' Add to the subtotal so far
        Me._subtotal += thisItemPrice

        ' Insert your code that calculates the tax and total, and
        ' updates the display
    End Sub
```

I recommend reading up on variable scope.

Comment: Hi Darryl. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following steps to solve it.

1. Define `decSubtotal` as a global variable, the initial value is 0
2. Save each added value.`decSubtotal += decItemPrice`
3. Please use `decSalesTax = Val(lblSubTotal.Text) * charge_SalesTax` instead of `decSalesTax = Val(txtItemPrice.Text) * charge_SalesTax`.
4. In addition, I suggest you can create a clear button to optimize the code. This will facilitate recalculation.

Detailed code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim decSubtotal As Decimal = 0
Private Sub btnCalc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    Const charge_SalesTax As Decimal = 0.05D
    Const charge_Shipping As Decimal = 6.5D

    Dim decItemPrice As Decimal
    Dim decSalesTax As Decimal
    Dim decShipping As Decimal
    Dim decTotalDue As Decimal

    Dim rndSalesTax As Decimal
    Dim rndTotalDue As Decimal

    decItemPrice = Val(txtItemPrice.Text)
    decSubtotal += decItemPrice
    lblSubTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(decSubtotal)
    decSalesTax = Val(lblSubTotal.Text) * charge_SalesTax
    rndSalesTax = Math.Round(decSalesTax, 2)
    lblSalesTax.Text = Convert.ToString(rndSalesTax)
    decShipping = charge_Shipping
    lblShipping.Text = Convert.ToString(decShipping)
    decTotalDue = decSubtotal + decSalesTax + decShipping
    rndTotalDue = Math.Round(decTotalDue, 2)
    lblTotalDue.Text = Convert.ToString(rndTotalDue)
End Sub

Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    decSubtotal = 0
    txtItemPrice.Text = ""
    lblSalesTax.Text = "lblSalesTax"
    lblShipping.Text = "lblShipping"
    lblSubTotal.Text = "lblSubTotal"
    lblTotalDue.Text = "lblTotalDue"
End Sub
End Class
```

Result：

[image]

Comment: No Val please. .Net has much better  methods.

Comment: Hi Arya. Thank you for your help.